# Why is my code giving different answers on Online Judge and locally?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to competitive programming and I've ran into this problem a couple of times already in CodeForces and I'm not really sure what's happening.

The thing is that when I run this code (example from http://codeforces.com/contest/1041/problem/B):

```
#include <iostream>

long gcd (long n1, long n2) {
    return (n2 == 0) ? n1 : gcd (n2, n1 % n2);
}

long min(long a, long b){
  return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main(){
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

  long a, b, x, y;

  std::cin >> a >> b >> x >> y;

  long g = gcd(x, y);

  std::cout << min(a / (x / g), b / (y / g)) << std::endl;
```

With the input of (4th input of the problem in the codeforces page)

```
1000000000000000000 1000000000000000000 999999866000004473 999999822000007597
```

Locally I get the right answer which is

```
1000000063
```

But when I send it to CodeForces, it gives me "Wrong Answer" and when I go check what answer it got, it says

```
0
```

To check if it was something I'm doing wrong with my code or not, I [coded the same thing in Java](https://repl.it/repls/VengefulStarchyCharacter) and it worked just fine.

So I checked if it was something to do with the version I was sending it as (C++17) sending in a different version (C++11), but got "Wrong Answer" again but with the answer

```
1
```

So I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong with my C++ code that it doesn't run as expected in the Online Judge.

PS.
I tried running it on valgrind but I didn't seem to get any warnings as well.

Comment: `long` might be 4-bytes on CF while 8-bytes on your machine. Try using `long long` which is practically 8-bytes everywhere.

Comment: Especially given the 'I coded it as Java' test I think @iBug is correct. In Java (and clearly on your system) long is 64 bits but it doesn't have to be. Try `uint64_t` for a guaranteed 64 bits

Comment: Get yourself an actual compiler and run your code.  You have the code, you have the test case, what is stopping you from compiling and testing the code yourself, thus discovering that the issue may be overflow?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The OP said he did it locally. It's not quite easy to get another environment where `long` is 4-bytes.

Comment: @iBug It was exactly that! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @LucasPellegrinelli *I'm fairly new to competitive programming* -- You really should know the exact compiler and compiler switches the "online judge" is using, else you're wasting your time if you do not know what obstacles you may be dealing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in comments,

> `long` might be 4-bytes on CF while 8-bytes on your machine. Try using `long long` which is practically 8-bytes everywhere.

In C++, the standard only enforces that `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)`, there's no guarantee that `long` would be 8 bytes or more. Some platforms may have `sizeof(long) == 8` like 64-bit Ubuntu or macOS. But [for Java, `long` is always 8-bytes long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). That's a subtle difference and often confuses people.

The C++ standard does require that `long long` be at least 8 bytes long, so you can safely use it as a signed 64-bit integer, or `unsigned long long` as an unsigned one.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Look at the minimal value-ranges, not the size in bits or bytes, however many bits a byte might hold.

Answer (score 9):

It seems `long` on Codeforces is only 4 bytes and can store only upto 2,147,483,647 while it can store larger value (maybe 8 bytes) in your local environment.

You can add `#include <cstdint>` and use the type `int64_t` to use 8-byte signed integer with more compatibility.

Comment: Perfect! The problem was exactly with the 4-byte long. But instead of using your int64_t solution, I tried with the @iBug solution which does not involve including another library (using long long). Thank you!

Comment: @LucasPellegrinelli Using `int64_t` does *not* mean using "another library". It just means using a different part of the standard library your code is already using. Besides, `int64_t` is probably just a type alias for `long long` anyway, but a more *explicit* one (and explicit is usually better).